# Remove Print Receipt from thank you page

Tags: magento2

Please check the Screenshot below. I want to remove Print receipt title from thank you purchase page, this page appears after placing a successful order.

[image: Print Receipt]

Answer (score 4):

Create this layout file in your theme here

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_onepage_success.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.success.print.button" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Then please run below commands once

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: will try this and update you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to extend the below template in your custom theme.

> From
>   vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/button.phtml
>   to
>   app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/button.phtml

And comment below code.

```
<a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getPrintUrl() ?>" target="_blank" class="print">
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Print receipt') ?>
    </a>
```

Comment: I check both the file location, vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/button.phtml - this was already the same code as you mentioned.
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/button.phtml - this is not found should I create folder and add the file ?

Comment: Yes you need to add that's why i mentioned path....

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: tell me what you did?